# Best way to handle global state

Tags: php, design-patterns

I was wondering if anyone could offer some advice on 'best practices' for using global state in a web application - specifically PHP, although im looking for generic best practices i.e. design patterns etc.

At the moment I just use a static class, calling it Configs.  I suppose this is similar to using the registry pattern but surely there is a more elegant way of handling global data within an application - i just cant think of a better way though.

Comment: *"remember that any global data is always guilty until proven innocent."* - Martin Fowler

Answer (score 2):

Options for handling global data in PHP in order of preference:

- Dependency injection
- Global Registry
- Singleton (using one purely to make something global is an abuse)
- Static classes (code smell)
- Global variables (sound klaxon)

There might be more, but that's all I could think of. Each has their own advantages and disadvantages, and the developer has to make a judgement call about when to use which. Dependency injection is usually the best choice, but not always. Sometimes (VERY RARELY) even global variables might be appropriate.

I just wrote a blog post with more details about the advantages and disadvantages of each, along with examples of when you might choose to use them: [Example here](http://russellscottwalker.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/handling-global-data-in-php-web_7.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only concerned with managing the global scope inside of each request, a simple Registry pattern is sufficient.

Zend_Registry works fine if you want some library code to lean on, and can be used without the rest of the Zend Framework stuff.

Or you can roll your own class if you prefer, as you say you're doing now.

Comment: so, the registry pattern is considered best practice for handling global data then?

Comment: So long as you can't make that global data non-global, Registry is arguably a best practice.